# importing .sql3 and csv file into mysql workbench

Tags: csv, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench

This is may be foolish question. But i cant find the answer of this problem anywhere.

i have a .sql3 and a .csv file i want do import functionality in my mysql workbench using any of these file.

right now i dont have any tables and shemas in my mysql

when i am importing  my demo.csv or demo.sql3 files in my workbench its showing an error like

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQLite format 3' at line 1

I am on ubuntu

can anyone help me out from this problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading csv data into MySQL [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) is probably the best way to go. There's a plugin in MySQL WOrkbench for importing CSV data but it requires an existing result set.